# Issue with procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following procedure (one of my first procedures in MySQL):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS usp_deposit_money;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_deposit_money(IN account_id INT,IN money_amount

DECIMAL(19,4))

BEGIN

START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE accounts 

SET accounts.balance = accounts.balance + money_amount

WHERE accounts.id = account_id;    

IF money_amount <= 0

THEN 

    ROLLBACK;

ELSE

   COMMIT;

END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

But I get the following error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_deposit_money(IN account_id INT,IN money_amou' at line 1

Comment: Compiles for me, what gui are you using?

Comment: Check the code here: http://rextester.com/WYDH65113

Comment: I don't think rextester requires you to set delimiters. As I said it compiles as coded in mysql.